# Python Multiple Inheritance Example

Tags: python, class, python-2.7, multiple-inheritance, super

I have this situation

```
class A(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super(B, self).__init__()

    def method(self):
        self.x += 1

class C(A):

    def __init__(self):
        super(C, self).__init__()

    def method(self):
        self.y += 1

class D(B, C):

    def __init__(self):
        super(D, self).__init__()

    def method(self):
        print self.x
        print self.y
```

I want D to print 1 for both x and y, but it is printing 0.
I don't fully understand multiple inheritance/super/etc... and while I have been trying to read the docs, an explanation on the example would be very helpful to me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a D object , it will never call method that named 'method'. 
It will just call parent's '**init**' method. So x or y will not change.

Answer (score 2):

If you override a method like `method` in your example, but still want to get the behavior of the base class as well as your own, you need to use `super` to call the version of the method you're overriding.

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0

    def method(self):  # we need a verion of method() to end the super() calls at
        pass

class B(A):
    def method(self):
        super(B, self).method() # call overridden version of method()
        self.x += 1

class C(A):
    def method(self):
        super(C, self).method() # here too
        self.y += 1

class D(B, C):
    def method(self):
        super(D, self).method() # and here
        print self.x
        print self.y
```

I've removed the unnecessary `__init__` methods in your child classes. There's no need to override a method unless you're changing its behavior, and none of the later `__init__` methods did anything other than call their predecessor.

Answer (score 0):

You can also call the method for the inherited classes within your D subclass
class D(B, C):

```
def __init__(self):
    B.__init__(self)
    C.__init__(self)

def method(self):
    B.method(self)
    C.method(self)
    print(self.x)
    print(self.y)
```